# Equivalence classes of relation $\rho: (x,y)\in \rho \Leftrightarrow (\exists k \in \mathbb{Z})x-y=3k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

I don't understand how equivalence classes are
$$C(1)=\{3k+1:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
$$C(2)=\{3k+2:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
$$C(3)=\{3k:k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Could someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is that when you divide an integer by another, via the euclidean algorithm,  there's a unique remainder.  So, dividing by 3 gives us a unique remainder that is 0, 1, or 2.  The equivalence relationship here is that two numbers have the same remainder.  Here's the reason:

$x=3q_1+r_1$,  $y=3q_2+r_2$,  where $q_1,q_2$ are the quotients and $r_1, r_2$ are the remainder.   Well,  what does it mean to have the same remainder?  Then $r_1=r_2$,  so $x-y=3q_1+r_1-3q_2-r_2=3q_1-3q_2=3(q_1-q_2)$.   Call $q_1-q_2=k$, and thus we have the two numbers have the same remainder if there exists a k such that $x-y=3k$.

Now, the equivalence classes are just saying numbers that have 0, 1, 2 as the remainder and any $k$ as the quotient.  So $C(3)$ are the multiples of 3,  $C(1)$ are the ones that leave a remainder of 1, and $C(2)$ are the ones that leave a remainder of 2.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
3k&3k+1&3k+2\\
0&1&2\\
3&4&5\\
6&7&8\\
9&10&11\\
12&13&14\\
15&16&17
\end{array}$$
Got the idea? The columns are the equivalence classes.